# Scrapy - scraped website authentication token expires while scraping

Tags: python, authentication, scrapy

To scrape a particular website 180 days into the future, an authentication token must be obtained in order to get the json data to scrape. While scraping, the token expires and the HTTP response returns a status code of 401 "Unauthorized". How do I get a new token into the scraper and continue scraping? Any help is appreciated.

```
def start_requests(self):
    return [Request(url=AUTHORIZATION_URL, callback=self.request_ride_times)]

def request_ride_times(self, response):
    # parse json data
    data = json.loads(response.body)

    # get auth token
    auth = '{}'.format(data['access_token'])

    # set auth token in headers
    headers = {'Authorization': 'BEARER {}'.format(auth)}

    # note: this probably isn't really necessary but it doesn't hurt (all the sites times we are scraping are in EST)
    now = get_current_time_for_timezone("US/Eastern")

    # get ending timeframe for scraping dates - 190 days out
    until = now + SCRAPE_TIMEFRAME

    for filter_type in FILTER_TYPES:
        filter_url_query_attr = '&filters={}'.format(filter_type)

        scrape_date = now

        while scrape_date <= until:
            url = urljoin(SCRAPE_BASE_URL, '{}{}&date={}'.format(SCRAPE_BASE_URL_QUERY_STRING, filter_url_query_attr, scrape_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))
            yield Request(url, headers=headers, callback=self.parse_ride_times, errback=self.error_handler)

            scrape_date += timedelta(days=1)

def parse_ride_times(self, response):
    # parse json data
    data = json.loads(response.body)

    for index, ride_details in enumerate(data['results']):

        if 'schedule' not in ride_details:
            continue

        ride_schedule = ride_details['schedule']

        # create item...

            yield item
```

Comment: I laughed when I saw *180 days into the future*

Comment: The website has a schedule from today through 180 days from today. I want to get the schedule data for each day. Does that make sense?

Comment: I understand , I just thought it was funny. How are you authenticating initially?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - I'm initially authenticating using a start_requests function that returns a Request call to a website that gets the token. Then the callback in the request processes the response. Example:

`def start_requests(self):
        return [Request(url=AUTHORIZATION_URL, callback=self.request_ride_times)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. I had to override the Request object in order to set a new authorization token into the header when the token expires. I made the the token a global variable.

```
# override Request object in order to set new authorization token into the header when the token expires        
authorization_token = None

class AuthTokenRequest(Request):
    @property
    def headers(self):
        global authorization_token
        return Headers({'Authorization': 'BEARER {}'.format(authorization_token)}, encoding=self.encoding)

    @headers.setter
    def headers(self, value):
        pass
```

The overridden request is then used in the request in the while loop including an errback function *error_handler* which is called when the request fails. The *error_handler* function gets a new token, resets the global token variable and then resubmits the request with the new token. In the same request the *dont_filter* parameter has been set to *False* so the failed request can be reprocessed.

Two more functions were created. One called *handle_auth* was created to initially set the token in the global variable. The other is *start_first_run* which calls handle_auth and returns request_ride_times function. This is called in the start_requests Request.

```
def error_handler(self, failure):
    global authorization_token
    status = failure.value.response.status
    if status == 401:
        form_data = {'grant_type': 'assertion', 'assertion_type': 'public', 'client_id': 'WDPRO-MOBILE.CLIENT-PROD'}
        auth_site_request = requests.post(url=AUTHORIZATION_URL, data=form_data)
        auth_site_response = json.loads(auth_site_request.text)
        disney_authorization_token = '{}'.format(auth_site_response['access_token'])

        yield failure.request

def start_requests(self):
    form_data = {'grant_type': 'assertion', 'assertion_type': 'public', 'client_id': 'WDPRO-MOBILE.CLIENT-PROD'}
    return [FormRequest(url=AUTHORIZATION_URL, formdata=form_data,
                        callback=self.start_first_run)]

def start_first_run(self, response):
    self.handle_auth(response)
    return self.request_ride_times()

def handle_auth(self, response):
    global authorization_token

    data = json.loads(response.body)

    # get auth token
    authorization_token = '{}'.format(data['access_token'])

def request_ride_times(self):
    # note: this probably isn't really necessary but it doesn't hurt (all the sites we are scraping are in EST)
    now = get_current_time_for_timezone("US/Eastern")

    # get ending timeframe for scraping dates - 190 days out
    until = now + SCRAPE_TIMEFRAME

    for filter_type in FILTER_TYPES:
        filter_url_query_attr = '&filters={}'.format(filter_type)

        scrape_date = now

        while scrape_date <= until:
            url = urljoin(SCRAPE_BASE_URL,
                          '{}{}&date={}'.format(SCRAPE_BASE_URL_QUERY_STRING,
                                                filter_url_query_attr, scrape_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))
            yield AuthTokenRequest(url, callback=self.parse_ride_times, errback=self.error_handler, dont_filter=True,
                                meta={"scrape_date": scrape_date})

            scrape_date += timedelta(days=1)

def parse_ride_times(self, response):
    # parse json data
    data = json.loads(response.body)
    # process data...
```